# C++ Pointer as a member of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm very new to Template Class and Template Function. So this time I tried to create my own Nullable class, that allows any object to have value, or null value.

```
template<typename _Type>
class Nullable
{
private: 
    _Type *_Pointer
public:
    Nullable::Nullable(const _Type &x)
    {
        this->_Pointer = new _Type(x);
    };
```

However, when I compile it, it returns me 2 errors:

- C2059: syntax error: 'this'
- C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

at the line of the constructor above.

So please explain to me how to write a constructor correctly for Template class. And is it recommended to use Pointer as a member of Template Class?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you syntactically inline functions, the namespace of the class you are in is implicitly added, so you were trying to define Nullable::Nullable::Nullable.

Comment: Another thing to think about is who is responsible for this memory you are allocating in your constructor, since your class isn't cleaning it up.   I'd recommend instead of using a raw pointer, to use std::unique_ptr<_Type> instead, so that the memory is automatically cleaned up when your Nullable object is destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

You are missing a `;` in the line:

```
_Type *_Pointer;
              ^^ missing
```

**Problem 2**

When a constructor is defined inline, you can't use the scope operator.

Change

```
Nullable::Nullable(const _Type &x) { ... }
```

to

```
Nullable(const _Type &x) { ... }
```

**A nitpick**

You don't need the `;` at the end of the constructor definition.

```
Nullable(const _Type &x)
{
    this->_Pointer = new _Type(x);
};
 ^^ Remove it.
```

It is not an error to have it there but it is not needed.

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works perfectly now. Sorry for missing the ';' :D